# how to sort date in Reactjs using sort function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i having a date data which is coming in the form of DD/MM/YY and i am trying to sort it like this

```
const[sortOrder,setsortOrder]=Usestate('default');
processedDataBychoice=UseMemo(()=>{
return data.map(row,index)=>{
row.main=a.data;
return row;
}
},[data])
}
const finalData=useMemo(()=>{
 processedDataByChoice.sort((rowA, rowB) => (new Date(rowB.main.last) - new Date(rowA.main.last)))
},[sortBy,sortOrder,processedDatabyChoice])

finalData.map((row, index) => {
main=row.main;
return(
<tr>{main.last}</tr>
);
);
```

but the data is not getting sorted any other way or i am doing something wrong in the code.

Comment: What's the data? What is the current output? What should the output be? Please show, not tell.

Comment: input is an array of dates and the ans should be sorted array of dates

Comment: @yash - It is always better to check if your dates are valid or not first, if any of those objects is invalid, it might be an issue. Can you add more code about how you are verifying if it's working or not.

Comment: @YashBontala please show us using a [mcve].

Comment: i have added the additional details i think that should be sufficient to answer if you want some more than i will add more

Comment: yes the data is coming right only

Comment: Please also share what `processedDataByChoice` is. (Show, not describe)

Comment: yaa i have added that detail too

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
processedDataByChoice.sort((rowA, rowB) => ((new Date(rowB.main.last)).getTime() - (new Date(rowA.main.last)).getTime()))
```

Comment: doesn't difference between two valid date objects anyway return a numeric value? So what will be the advantage of using `getTime()` method here?